# Should I keep these three plants in one pot?

Tags: houseplants

I bought this pot with five small plants in it last summer but when I brought them home they grew too fast and I had to change the pot and remove two of them. Maybe this happened because they had too much light in my living room and I was told at the floral shop that they don't need much light and water.
[image]

I took a much bigger pot and planted three of them in it. Also I moved it in a place where they get less light but they are growing anyway. I would like to know if I should keep them together or separate into different pots. 
Also if someone can tell me what kind of plants are these.
Thank you!

[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two Crotons and a Dracaena Marginata hybrid. To my understanding, they need light, but the seller may have meant shade tolerant. Their final size is much bigger. Potting them alone in bigger pots (than what they had in the first picture) is more adequate and will present them in all their glory. Sure, you can keep them together for aesthetic reasons. There is no wrong with this.

Your arrangement in the pink pot is fine and well balanced. It is up to you to decide how tall they can grow. The Dracaena can be cut lower if you decide to limit its height. At first, it will appear like a stick staring at you. With time, two and sometimes three new shoots come out of the tip. Pruning the Croton is more straightforward. The trimmings can be used as new cuttings.

One good method is to separate and pot-up, or even plant in the garden and restart this arrangement with cuttings from plants that once grew there. This way you can keep a compact size for a long time.